# Cleaning up my delay timer

Tags: java, timer, refactoring, awt

I made a game where you're a circle that moves around the screen and dodges other circles as they spawn on the screen. I have a delay timer that spawn an Enemy at a certain time, but it's not very good coding, as I'm kind of new to Java. If anyone could neaten up the code or give advice on how it could be better, I would really appreciate it.

NOTE: spawnTime is a long set to System.currentTimeMillis(), timesDelay is a double set to 1.0, and spawnRateCounter is an int set to 0. Also, this code is being run in an awt Timer so it's being run again and again.

```
private final double delayRateChange = .75;

private void spawnEnemy() {
    Random r = new Random();
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - spawnTime > (1000 * timesDelay)){
        spawnRateCounter++;
        if (spawnRateCounter == 5){
            timesDelay*=delayRateChange;
            spawnRateCounter = 0;
        }
        enemies.add(new Enemy(r.nextInt(500), r.nextInt(500),
                r.nextInt(4), r.nextInt(4) + 1, r.nextInt(3)));
        spawnTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work in your code that you need help fixing?

Comment: Similar comment to above, what do you mean by "its not very good"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the only comment I can make here is that you are "constructing" random every time the method is called.

Typically what I do is add Random to a utils class something along the lines of:

```
public class Utils () {
   private static Random random;

   private Utils(){}  //Only static methods

   public static final Random getRandom() {
       if(random == null) random = new Random();
       return random;
   }

   public static final seedRandom(long seed) {
       random = new Random(seed);
   }
```

Then in your code you would replace:

```
Random r = new Random();
```

with

```
Random r = Utils.getRandom();
```

Comment: Thanks, would the Util class be used for other things too? Would I be able to include other java.util items in there as well?